# Access handsontable methods/properties using nghandsontable

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I'm using [ngHandsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable) Angular directive for [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/).  I managed to show the data successfully, but I'm struggling with getting access to the modified rows so I can send the data to the DB.
I tried binding the afterChange callback, but the index seems to be off after column sorting. (shows the index of the row shown on the table, not in the dataSource)

I wonder what's the best practice to save ngHandsontable data or what I should do to access the API like getData method or columnSorting property

Thanks a lot for your help!
- Marco

Comment: I looked into this issue and tried to find a solution. Unfortunately this has turned out to be very hard because the documentation for ngHandsontable is dreadful to say the least. I would advice you to post some sample code displaying your issue or creating a plnkr that shows your progress so far. All I have been able to find now is [this](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/issues/34) git issue that just vaguely describes a possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using afterInit event to get the instance and then call the methods in further events like the afterChange.

This is how my code looks like:

```
afterInit: function() {
        $scope.hot.instance = this;
    }
```

and then:

```
afterChange: function (changes, source) {
        if (source != 'loadData') {          
            var hot = $scope.hot.instance;
            var dataRow = hot.getSourceDataAtRow(index)
            // .... saveChanges...
        };
    }
```

Thanks a lot to Bricktop for giving me the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with this sort of logic:

```
post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
    var hotDiv = iElement.find("div[hot-table]")

    var hotInstance = hotDiv.isolateScope().hotInstance;
    hotInstance.addHook('afterLoadData', function(){
        console.log("loaded data");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use view model in the controller

```
var vm = this;
```

and then you can call any of the core handsontable method of this view model like

```
this.getCell()

this.getSourceDataAtRow()
```